# Image as Header of a Table View Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I created a UITableView that gets its content from a txt- File and now implemented a SearchBar programmatically as the tableHeaderView. 
Do you have an idea how I can put an Image (In my case an emblem) on the top of everything ?
I looked for it on the internet but didn't find a solution for my problem. 
I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: add a `UIView` with `UISearchBar` and `UIImage` as `TableViewHeaderView`

Comment: What JuicyFruit said is correct. A table view header is just a custom UIView provided by the UITableViewDataSource. Figure out how to build your custom UIView, then simply return it from viewForHeaderInSection, and make sure that you also correctly set the header height.

Comment: Do you want to let the image to cover the search bar?

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: No , I don't want the image to cover the search bar

Comment: can you show picture of how you want and what it currently looks like!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in viewDidLoad

```
let view = UIView(frame: yourviewFrame)
 //make button and set action and add into view
 //make one image view 
 view.addSubview(your imageview)
 //set view into tablefooterview
self.yourtableoutlet.tableHeaderView = view
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an `UiView`over everything (u must be a bit precise lol), then increase the height of this view and put what u want inside it.

Hope can help you.

p.s : Consider to use `UiTableView` inside a `UiViewController` instead use 'UiTableViewController' (you have only to set delegates ).
However u must remember that using `UiTableView` inside a `UiViewController` u can't display a static content.

Answer (score 0):

do the following code in viewForHeaderInSection :

```
let view = UIView(frame: yourviewFrame)

 view.addSubview(your searchbar)

 view.addSubview(your imageview)

return view
```